# How to set simple admin password?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1.9 I just edited the `admin_user` table in database and set password to the hash of 'admin', so I got admin admin for short on development local installation.

How to do it in Magento 2? I did the same change, but it just broke admin account, so I no longer can log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what helped me :

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxadmin', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

I have ran this against a database. This is probably very unsecure, so can be used only during development.

Comment: Insecure--yes. There's a reason Magento doesn't let you set simple passwords out-of-box anymore. Please use a password manager instead.